# Auto-login in nuxtjs using only token

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

I have a mobile app that uses laravel passport as a mean of authentication (no problem here). In the mobile app, I added a button that will theoretically redirect me to my web app (same auth endpoint as the mobile) and automatically logs me in. How can I achieve this using nuxtjs (with nuxt auth already used)? Can't find a way to login using only the token in nuxt auth or hack it.

Please feel free to add if you have any suggestions or recommendations.

I imagine something like this but no luck.

```
            this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
                data: {
                    token: token <--------------------------- token from url (originated in mobile app)
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                // successful login
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // failed login
            });
```

This is my sample url that I want to automatically login in nuxtjs

```
http://example.com/redirect?token=tokenvaluehere
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as you, but instead of laravel passport I used jwt-auth with local Strategy.
I achieve the auto-login functionality using the code below. Maybe it helps:

```
    const route = ''; // Route from where to get the Token
    this.$auth.reset().then(() => {
      this.$axios.get(route)
          .then(({data}) => {
            this.$auth.setStrategy('local').then(() => {

              const token = this.$auth.strategy.options.tokenType
                  ? this.$auth.strategy.options.tokenType + ' ' + data.login_token
                  : data.login_token

              this.$auth.setToken('local', token)
              this.$auth.strategy._setToken(token)
              this.$auth.fetchUser()
            })
          })
    })
```